Are unofficial transcripts required to show a cumulative GPA?
When I requested the transcript from my undergraduate institution, I was provided with a result sheet (semester GPA and credits were included; but no cumulative GPA).
Does this count as an unofficial transcript?

Will they directly send a transcript to the institutions you are applying to? Do they have 'official' transcripts (usually including a nice embossed seal to show it is official)?

Have you completed your undergraduate study? Some institutions do not include a cumulative GPA in year-/semester-wise transcripts but include this in the final transcript.

Where is your undergraduate institution located?

@AzorAhai-him-, that tag indicates US.

@Buffy Occasionally, people use that tag to indicate they want to apply to a U.S. institution, not necessarily that's where they're applying from.

Unless the application says otherwise, an unofficial transcript does not need to have a cumulative GPA.
By "official transcript" I mean one that is sent directly from the school to the recipient - whether digitally or physically - and may incur a cost. And by "unofficial transcript," I mean a free version that a student can request any time. Some programs request unofficial transcripts to save applicants money, and may request a secure official transcript before enrollment.
Graduate schools understand universities differ in their transcript form and GPA is an easy calculation.

Your definition of "unofficial" may differ from that of the OP. The recipient in this case is, in fact, the OP. An "application" can't require a cumulative GPA from another institution.

@Buffy I don't feel like rehashing the conversation we just had. [1] I am assuming that OP requested an "unofficial" transcript in order to send it to someone, and are wondering if it's complete. My answer is that it is: Someone asking for an unofficial transcript will not reject it if it doesn't have a cumulative GPA line. [2] Sure it could? An application could easily have a box that says "Cumulative GPA: ____".

But they can't ask the university to produce it. And, again, you are making assumptions that may not be valid.

@Buffy You are making assumptions, too, and I am not finding much likelihood in an assumption that OP only needs this for their personal use and yet also needs feedback about whether the thing they have "counts" as an unofficial transcript.

@Buffy "But they can't ask the university to produce it." What are you talking about?

University A can't force or require University B to compute a cumulative GPA.

@Buffy I didn't claim they did? In fact, I said that OP's transcript would be accepted as an unofficial transcript even without a cumulative GPA, for the very point you raise.
